# Can you GET Rally API requirements, defects, and all tasks with one query

Tags: json, task, rally

Currently I have to make multiple GETs to receive all the information which I need

- User Story: FormattedID, _refObjectName, State, Owner._refObjectName
- Tasks for each User Story: FormattedID, _refObjectName, State, Owner._refObjectName
- Defect: FormattedID, _refObjectName, State, Owner._refObjectName
- Tasks for each Defect: FormattedID, _refObjectName, State, Owner._refObjectName

For all of the User Stories I use:

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.26/hierarchicalrequirement.js?query=((Project.Name = "**[projectName]**") and (Iteration.Name = "**[iterationName]**"))&fetch=true&start=1&pagesize=100

For all of the Defects I use:

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.26/defects.js?query=((Project.Name = "**[projectName]**") and (Iteration.Name = "**[iterationName]**"))&fetch=true&start=1&pagesize=100

Within each of these, if they have any Tasks, they display as:

```
{
  "_rallyAPIMajor": "1",
  "_rallyAPIMinor": "26",
  "_ref": "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.26/task/9872916743.js",
  "_refObjectName": "Update XYZ when ABC",
  "_type": "Task"
}
```

This doesn't have all the information I need, so I hit each of the Tasks' _ref URLs to get the full task information.

This adds up to sometimes 80+ AJAX calls per page load.

Is there a better query which would provide the extra Task information up front?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fetch parameter can be tricky with queries. If you provide `fetch=true` you will get all of the fields that exist on the queried type (Story,Defect). If the field is also a domain object (like a tasks or a defect) you will only get the thin ref object like this

```
    {
       "_ref": "/task/1234.js"  
    }
```

If you want to get fields populated on the sub-objects you will need to specify the fields you want shown in the fetch param `fetch=Name,FormattedID,Tasks`. This would return an object like the one below:

```
{
      "HierarchicalRequirement" : {
        "Name" : "StoryName",
        "FormattedID" : "S1234",
        "Tasks" : [
          {
            "_rallyAPIMajor": "1",
            "_rallyAPIMinor": "26",
            "_ref": "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.26/task/9872916743.js",
            "_refObjectName": "Update XYZ when ABC",
            "_type": "Task",
            "FormattedID" : "T1",
            "Name" : "Update XYZ when ABC"
          }
        ]
      }
 }
```

Let me know if that helped

Comment: Thank you Charles!  I just gave it a spin and it seems like it will work.  I will verify this in the office on Monday and upvote & mark answered if this is the case.  Can you please tell me where you found this information from?  I've been looking through https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/index.jsp and have not been able to find an example like what you've posted -- maybe I've been looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Hi Charles, it works nicely, but I still have to specify two queries (which is alot better than 80!).  I'm wondering if there is a special way to get results from both heirarchicalrequirement.js and defects.js simultaneously?  I tried including fetch=Defects in the HR query, but it didn't work.

Comment: If you use the [batch]https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/batch.jsp) endpoint you can get them in one request. In my experience it is usually about as fast to do the two requests to the story and defect endpoints. 

Also you may find our [SDK](http://developer.rallydev.com/help/app-sdk) helpful if you are trying to use Rally data in an external mannor.

Comment: fetch=Name,FormattedID,TaskStatus,Tasks appears to be not as useful in API v2. No more _refObjectName

`"Tasks":{
               "_rallyAPIMajor":"2",
               "_rallyAPIMinor":"0",
               "_ref":"https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/HierarchicalRequirement/14229197581/Tasks",
               "_type":"Task",
               "Count":0
            },`